# Actors from any part of Star Trek who also acted in the Orville. I can list a few. Have I missed any?

Tags: star-trek, actors, the-orville

I have noticed a number of actors from various parts of the *Star Trek* franchise also playing parts in *The Orville*. Seth MacFarlane is obviously a huge *Star Trek* fan.

- Marina Sirtis played a teacher in *The Orville*'s onboard school.
- Penny Johnson Jerald played Chief Medical Officer Claire Finn.
- Robert Picardo  played Xelayan Ildis Kitan, the father of Alara Kitan.
- John Billingsley played Xelayan Cambis Borrin in the *The Orville* episode “[Home](https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/Home).”

Have I missed any?

Comment: Off the top of my head - Seth MacFarlane himself guest starred on Enterprise. Tim Russ portrayed Doctor Sherman in Season 2. But there are many more: https://screenrant.com/orville-star-trek-actors-cameos-every/

Comment: Seth MacFarlane himself played an engineer named Ensign Rivers in two episodes of Enterprise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There have been a considerable number of individuals who [share an acting credit](https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?roles=tt5691552,tt0092455) in both *The Orville* and a *Star Trek* property.

| Name | Orville Character / First Appearance | Trek Character / First Appearance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **[Scott Grimes](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0342241/?ref_=sr_t_1)** | Old Wounds (as Lt. Malloy) | TNG: Evolution (as Crewman Eric) |
| **[Marina Sirtis](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000642/?ref_=sr_t_2)** | Sanctuary (as Teacher) | TNG: Encounter at Farpoint (as Deanna Troi) |
| **[Brian Thompson](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0859921/?ref_=sr_t_3)** | Into the Fold (as Drogan) | TNG: A Matter of Honor (as Lt. Klag) |
| **[Robert Knepper](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0460694/?ref_=sr_t_4)** | If the Stars Should Appear (as Hamelac) | TNG: Haven (as Wyatt Miller) |
| **[Tony Todd](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0865302/?ref_=sr_t_7)** | Sanctuary (as Moclan Delegate) | TNG: Sins of the Father (as Kurn, Son of Mogh) |
| **[Penny Johnson Jerald](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0425982/?ref_=sr_t_8)** | Old Wounds (as Dr. Finn) | TNG: Homeward (as Dobara) |
| **[Simon Templeman](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0854742/?ref_=sr_t_9)** | Shadow Realms (as Krill Consul) | TNG: The Defector (as John Bates) |
| [**Tim Russ**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0750913/?ref_=sr_t_10) | Lasting Impressions (as Dr. Sherman) | TNG: Starship Mine (as Devor) |
| **[Ron Canada](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0133474/?ref_=sr_t_11)** | Command Performance (as Admiral Tucker) | TNG: The Masterpiece Society (as Martin Benbeck) |
| [**John Fleck**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0281387/?ref_=sr_t_12) | Blood of Patriots (as Krill Ambassador) | TNG: The Mind's Eye (as Taibek) |
| **[Wren T. Brown](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0114931/?ref_=sr_t_13)** | Deflectors (as Captain Retchik) | TNG: Manhunt (as Transporter Pilot) |
| **[James Horan](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0394533/?ref_=sr_t_14)** | Krill (as Sazeron) | TNG: Suspicions (as Dr. Jo'Bril) |
| **[JD Cullum](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0191631/?ref_=sr_t_16)** | Command Performance (as Calivon Zoo Administrator) | TNG: Redemption (as Toral) |
| **[Joel Swetow](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0842498/?ref_=sr_t_19)** | Old Wounds (as Krill Captain) | TNG: Firstborn (as Yog) |
| [**Josef Cannon**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1184573/?ref_=sr_t_24) | Sanctuary (as Moclan Delegate #2) | TNG: The Icarus Factor (as Klingon Warrior) |
| **[Molly Hagan](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0353243/?ref_=sr_t_2)** | Firestorm (as Drenala Kitan) | DS9: The Jem'Hadar (as Eris) |
| **[Brian George](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0353243/?ref_=sr_t_2)** | Old Wounds (as Dr. Aronov) | DS9: Doctor Bashir, I Presume (as Richard Bashir) |
| [**Lisa Banes**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0051862/?ref_=sr_t_9) | Gently Falling Rain (as Speria Balask) | DS9: Equilibrium (as Dr. Renhol) |
| **[Andy Milder](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0586994/?ref_=sr_t_12)** | A Tale of Two Topas (as Ensign Bolobar) | DS9: Empok Nor (as Boq'ta) |
| [**Robert Curtis Brown**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0193551/?ref_=sr_t_13) | All The World is Birthday Cake (as Chief Advisor Makkal) | DS9: Sanctuary (as Vedek Sorad) |
| **[J. Paul Boehmer](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0091227/?ref_=sr_t_15)** | Cupid's Dagger (as Krill High Priest) | DS9: Tacking Into the Wind (as Vornar |
| **[Stephen Blackehart](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0002888/?ref_=sr_t_16)** | Identity, Part II (as Krill Second Officer) | DS9: The Dogs of War (as Starfleet Officer) |
| **[Loren Lester](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0504489/?ref_=sr_t_19)** | Majority Rule (as Lewis) | DS9: The Quickening (as Attendant) |
| **[D. Elliot Woods](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0940555/?ref_=sr_t_28)** | About a Girl (as Moclan Council Foreman) | DS9: Sons of Mogh (as Klingon Officer) |
| [**Robert Picardo**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000585/?ref_=sr_t_6) | Firestorm (as Ildis Kitan) | VOY: Caretaker (as The EMH Doctor) |
| **[Jason Alexander](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004517/?ref_=sr_t_1)** | Ja'loja (as Olix) | VOY: Think Tank (as Kurros) |
| **[James Read](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0416856/?ref_=sr_t_8)** | Shadow Realms (as Admiral Christie) | VOY: Workforce (as Jaffen) |
| **[John Rubinstein](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0748270/?ref_=sr_t_12)** | All The World is Birthday Cake (as Prefect) | The '37s (as John Evansville) |
| **[Seth MacFarlane](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0532235/?ref_=sr_t_1)** | Old Wounds (as Captain Ed Mercer) | ENT: The Forgotten (as Ensign Rivers) |
| [**John Billingsley**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0082517/?ref_=sr_t_6) | Home (as Cambis Borrin) | ENT: Broken Bow, Part I (as Dr. Phlox) |
| **[Derek Mears](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0575216/?ref_=sr_t_7)** | Cupid's Dagger (as Bruidian Ambassador) | ENT: Borderland (as Orion Guard) |
| [**Steven Culp**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0191688/?ref_=sr_t_8) | Majority Rule (as Willks) | ENT: The Xindi (as Major Hayes) |
| [**Philip Anthony-Rodriguez**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1271152/?ref_=sr_t_13) | Mad Idolatry (as Fadolin) | ENT: Horizon (as Juan) |
| [**Lamont Thompson**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1476956/?ref_=sr_t_19) | About a Girl (as Kaybrak) | ENT: Cold Front (as Alien Pilgrim) |
| [**Brett Rickaby**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0725434/?ref_=sr_t_20) | Command Performance (as Lurenek) | ENT: Twilight (as Yedrin Koss) |
| **[Matt Kaminsky](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0436751/?ref_=sr_t_21)** | Majority Rule (as Interviewer) | ENT: Singularity (as Cunningham) |
| **[Chase Kim](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2101748/?ref_=sr_t_22)** | Sanctuary (as Officer) | ENT: Stratagem (as MACO R. Azar) |
| [**Regi Davis**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0205318/?ref_=sr_t_26) | Sanctuary (as Dr. Kalba) | ENT: Unexpected (as Klingon Officer |
| **[**Michael Duisenberg**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1570545/)** | If the Stars Should Appear (as Uniformed Man) | ENT: Unexpected (as Crewman) |
| **[Corey Mendell-Parker](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0662162/?ref_=sr_t_28)** | Majority Rule (as Policeman #1) | ENT: Horizon (as Paul Mayweather) |
| **[Jack McBrayer](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1442113/?ref_=sr_t_4)** | Twice in a Lifetime (as Actor #1) | LD: Terminal Provocations (as Badgey) |
| **[Robin Atkin Downes](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0235960/?ref_=sr_t_5)** | Blood of Patriots (as Krill Captain Jackazh) | LD: Wej Duj (as Togg) |
| **[Jon Curry](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0193087/?ref_=sr_t_7)** | Gently Falling Rain (as Krill Cmndr) | LD: Wej Duj (as Ma'Ah) |
| [**Isabelle Meneses**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm12659285/?ref_=sr_t_15) | Gently Falling Rain (as Xeleyan Annie) | PIC: Watcher (as Small Girl) |
| **[Ernesto Chaverri](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3420704/?ref_=sr_t_21)** | Krill (as Bandito) | PIC: Broken Pieces (as Xborg) |
| [**Gwen Van Dam**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0885934/?ref_=sr_t_6) | Majority Rule (as Grandmother) | Star Trek Generations (as El Aurian Survivor) |
| [**F. Murray Abraham**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000719/?ref_=sr_t_2) | Sanctuary (as Chairman) | Star Trek: Insurrection (as Ru'Afo) |
| [**Rico E. Anderson**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1066970/?ref_=sr_t_7) | About a Girl (as Moclan Doctor) | Star Trek (2009) (as Captain Kelley Bogel) |
| **[Eddie Davenport](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2591886/?ref_=sr_t_5)** | If the Stars Should Appear (as Guard #1) | Star Trek Into Darkness (as USS Vengeance Security Officer) |

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, I've checked everyone listed as "Actor" on their bio against the [collaboration search](https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?roles=tt5691552,tt0092455) and credits on IMDB. I've used [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek#:~:text=(1999%E2%80%932003)-,Films%20and%20television,-Film(s)) and checked all the official movies, TV shows and animated shows. I've excluded a dozen or so voice actors of various sorts.

Comment: I've also cross-checked against the list here on Memory Alpha ([Actors who have appeared in Star Trek and The Orville](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Orville#Actors_who_have_appeared_in_Star_Trek_and_The_Orville))

Comment: Awesome!. Thank you.

Comment: Robert Picardo played the Mk1 EMH in Voyager

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - If you see small fixes that need to be made, don't hesitate to use the [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/286721/edit) button :-)

Comment: Tim Russ was indeed in TNG but he was far more famous as Tuvok in Voyager.

Comment: @JudithJones - Alas, those are the breaks when you go for first appearance.